# Cisco Anyconnect VPN connection Issue from azure vm running Windows 11

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, cisco

I have a vm running on azure. I have installed Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility VPN Client.
I tried to connect to my organisation, but I am getting the following error.

```
 5:46:21 PM    Ready to connect.
 5:46:42 PM    Contacting ************.com/2fa.
 5:47:18 PM    User credentials entered.
 5:47:21 PM    Please respond to banner.
 5:47:23 PM    User accepted banner.
 5:47:23 PM    Establishing VPN session...
 5:47:23 PM    The AnyConnect Downloader is performing update checks...
 5:47:23 PM    Checking for profile updates...
 5:47:23 PM    Checking for product updates...
 5:47:23 PM    Establishing VPN session...
 5:47:23 PM    Establishing VPN - Initiating connection...
 5:47:24 PM    VPN establishment capability from a remote desktop is disabled.  A VPN connection will not be established.
 5:47:24 PM    AnyConnect was not able to establish a connection to the specified secure gateway. Please try connecting again.
 5:47:25 PM    Ready to connect.
```

How would I handle this situation.

Comment: Can you post configuration from the ASA?

Comment: in Cisco Anyconnect there is no IP address assigned.  Only thing where I can play around is on the azure vm's Vnet.

Comment: If you do not have access to the Cisco ASA, then there is nothing you can do to fix. The connections are blocked on the ASA, and you will need to contact the administrator and ask for AnyConnect access over RDP.

Comment: Great!!!, actually the issue was with the firewall on the org side. it would conclude if you can post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the logs, it appears that Connection is blocked by the VPN Concentrator (Cisco ASA). Usually a new Anyconnect Client Profile needs to be created on the ASA and AllowRemoteUsers selected. There is nothing that the end user can do with Client configuration to fix it. Based on chat conversation, user reached out to Firewall Administrator to fix the issue. Posting the conversation as an answer so the question can be closed.